# Fontspec 2.4 and Scale=MatchLowercase causes error

Tags: fontspec, scaling

I just updated to TeXLive 2014 and when compiling the following code using either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX I get an error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\begin{document}
\textsf{Example text}
\end{document}
```

The error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\__fontspec_calc_scale:n ..._tmpb_dim }\fp_div:Nn 
                                                  \l__fontspec_tmpa_fp {\l__...
l.3 ...font{Latin Modern Sans}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
```

If I remove the `[Scale=MatchLowercase]` bit then it compiles. If I use other font features (eg Numbers=Uppercase) it works. It's just the `Scale` command with either `MatchLowercase` or `MatchUppercase` that causes the error.

The font does not seem to matter nor does setting the sans or main font.

Comment: That's a known bug (fontspec uses a now deprecated command). It will hopefully be corrected soon.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, I didn't see the bug mentioned anywhere, thanks.

Comment: The version of `fontspec` now on CTAN has fixed this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`fontspec` uses the deprecated function `\fp_div:Nn` that has been removed from the base code. The removed function appears only once. Until the bug is fixed you can define the missing function:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}[2014/06/01] % the fix is just for this version

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \fp_div:Nn #1 #2
  {
   \fp_set:Nn #1 { #1/#2 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\begin{document}
\textsf{Example text}
\end{document}
```